# How to save file without the Excel VBA code in it?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code for saving the file without the VBA codes.

It saves together with the VBA codes.

```
Sheets.Select
Cells.Copy
Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\sgffa\Desktop\Profile_Macros\NEW\" & NFolder & "\" & "C", 
FileFormat:=xlExcel8
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it need to be saved as `.xls`, per the use of your `xlExcel8` file format specifier?

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="TestSave.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False`

Comment: @jsheeran Yes, that the problem. It has to be in .xls format.

Answer (score 0):

Save your project as xlsx instead of xlsm then the Code shouln'd be saved

Answer (score 0):

you could first copy sheets in a new workbook and then save it

```
Sheets.Copy
Sheets.Select
Cells.Copy
Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With ActiveWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .SaveAs "C:\Users\sgffa\Desktop\Profile_Macros\NEW\" & NFolder & "\" & "C.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    .Close True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

from

```
 ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\sgffa\Desktop\Profile_Macros\NEW\" & NFolder & "\" & "C", FileFormat:=xlExcel8
```

to this:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\sgffa\Desktop\Profile_Macros\NEW\" & NFolder & "\" & "C" & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Answer (score 0):

### SaveAs Confusion

I'm confused, too. As it happens, when you save your macro enabled workbook (.xlsm) as macro not-enabled workbook (.xlsx), the workbook stays open still having the code in it. But the good thing is that it is saved without code. You can now save it, 'manually' SaveAs it, it will still be without code (macros) the next time you open it.

The code should demonstrate the following:

- It is good practice to start with `Option Explicit` which will help
  you by alerting you when something is wrong.
- It is good practice to use constants at the beginning of the code,
  especially for such long file paths, so when you have to change them
  you can easily find them.
- When you disable an event, there is a possibility you won't be able
  to enable it again if you're not careful. If an error occurs, you should redirect
  the code to enable those events again.
- If you want to close the workbook, then use the line `ThisWorkbook.Close`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SaveMacroDisabled()

    Const strPath = "I:\Excel\MyDocuments\Test\Test4\"
    Const strXLSX = "BookMacroDisabled"

    On Error GoTo ProgramError

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs strXLSX, _
          FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault

SafeExit:

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' ThisWorkbook.Close

Exit Sub

ProgramError:

    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred"
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo SafeExit

End Sub
```